# Solving ODE $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r u_\theta))=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm preparing for an exam where you have to compute really fast, one of the ODE's encountered (by simplifying Navier-Stokes equations for a particular problem) is $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r u_\theta))=0$.

The solution is $u_\theta = \frac{C_1 r}{2} + \frac{C_2}{r}$.

I know I can write it out as $0=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r u_\theta))= \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(\frac{u_\theta}{r}+\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial r}) = \ln(r)u_\theta+\frac{\partial^2 u_\theta}{\partial r^2}$, and then solve by separtion of variables: $\ln(r) \,\partial r^2=-\frac{\partial^2 u_\theta}{u_\theta}$.

But this takes quite a long time and is very prone to errors, and gets rather messy with integration constants, is there no better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate once with respect to $r$ to get $$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(ru_{\theta}) = c_1$$ Multiply by $r$ and integrate again with respect to $r$ to get $$ru_{\theta} = \frac{c_1r^2}{2}+c_2$$ Divide both sides by $r$ to get $u_{\theta} = \frac{c_1r}{2}+\frac{c_2}{r}$.

Comment: Thanks! I initially thought about this, but then got confused and thought I might not be allowed to compute it like that. Which is silly now that I think about it, if I set the inner function to $q(r)$ I would have not had any objections (assuming integrability is satisfied). But yes this way is a lot faster (and safer).